# convert csv to json in Node js

Tags: node.js

Can any one help me in converting csv to json file. I am trying to write the code using Node js.

I have input file with two columns as:

```
Name    ,abc de
Role    ,role1; 
        ,role2
Address ,7, xyz 
        ,suburb 
        ,city, state
        ,country
///
Name    ,abc1 de1
Role    ,role3;
        ,role4 
Address ,8, xyz1 
        ,suburb1 
        ,city1, state1
        ,country1
///
```

I want the output as json:

```
[
    {Name:{first_name:abc, last_name:de}, 
    Role:[role1,role2], 
    Address:[7, xyz, suburb, city, state, country]},
    {Name:{first_name:abc1, last_name:de1},
    Role:[role3,role4], 
    Address:[8, xyz1, suburb1, city1, state1, country1]}
]

Many thanks in advance.
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson?activeTab=readme

Comment: If I look at input file, roles are separated by semicolon and address is separated by comma and attribute name is probably by tab, is the understanding correct? Can we have better input file or that's outside of your control?

Comment: I already tried with it. I couldn't get the expected output.

Comment: I have made changes to input file. Yes roles are separated with semicolon, address are separated by commas with multiple lines, first name and last name are separated by 20 spaces.

Comment: first name and last name are separated by 20 spaces???

Comment: yes it is. Actually, it was a flat file converted to csv.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS - Convert CSV to JSON Object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583219/nodejs-convert-csv-to-json-object-array)

Comment: I think the information is not enough, can you upload the sample flat file as as well as csv?

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this, but I still think we need a custom implementation to process each block, we may not bale to do it in one function

```js
var res = {};
var yourJsonString = `Name    ,abc de
Role    ,role1; 
        ,role2
Address ,7, xyz 
        ,suburb 
        ,city, state
        ,country`;
 res = yourJsonString.split('\n').map(processLine); 
 function processLine(data)
 {
       if(data.split(',')[0].indexOf("Name")>-1)
        { 
          return {Name: {first_name: data.split(',')[1].split(' ')[0],last_name:data.split(',')[1].split(' ')[1]}};
        }
 } 
 document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Many thanks for that. Can I please know how do I join two new lines (example: for role/ address)? I did some thing like this: else if (data.split(',')[0].indexOf("Role")>-1){
          return {Role:[data.split(',')[1].split(';')[0]]};

Comment: I think what we need is go through all lines and push data to separate arrays, for example all names array, roles array and address array and then use map function to process each type of array and then join them

Comment: I could do everything other than joining two lines. I am actually using fs.createReadStream(inPath). After I read first line, I couldn't able to move to second line.                         if (line[0] == 'NAME') {
     line = addName(line);
     outData.push(line); }